# Tkinter, unable to properly pack frames inside for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a window where multiple frames are packed one onto the other, each of them with a background image and a button. Here's the code I'm using:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

width = 4
height = 1
img_directory = "images/styles"
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

def add_canvas(frame, img):
    #The canvas is used to create a single block, which will contain the image and the button. Each canvas is put into a frame
    c = Canvas(frame, width=500, height=100)
    c.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    bg = c.create_image(10, 10, image=img)
    btn = Button(frame, text="go", width=width, height=height, background='black', fg="white")
    c.create_window(100, 220, window=btn)
    return c


for f in os.listdir(img_directory):
    frame = Frame(root)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(os.path.join(img_directory, f)))
    c = add_canvas(frame, img)
    frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately, the resulting window is completely empty. Nothing is displayed inside it. I tried manually creating a few frames and stacking them on each other and it works. So why it doesn't work if I use a loop? I have several frames so I need the loop, why it doesn't work?

Comment: You create a window of size 400x300, but you create canvases with size 500x100, so you can only see at most 3 canvases.  If there are more than 3 canvases created, you cannot see any image because only the image in the last canvas will be shown because you have used same variable to hold the image references in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a workaround, I can do without an open folder.

you are missing widget `pack()` for `Button` in line 16.

Look in between line 22-25.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
#from PIL import ImageTk, Image 
import os

width = 4
height = 1
img_directory = "images/styles"
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

def add_canvas(frame, img):
    #The canvas is used to create a single block, which will contain the image and the button. Each canvas is put into a frame
    c = Canvas(frame, width=500, height=100)
    c.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    bg = c.create_image(10, 10, image=img)
    btn = Button(frame, text="go", width=width, height=height, background='black', fg="white").pack()
    c.create_window(100, 220, window=btn)
    return c


 
frame = Frame(root)
img = PhotoImage(file='p1.png')
c = add_canvas(frame, img)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]